# Receive list of checkboxes in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view where multiple entitys are displayed which the user may then select or not. All of this works fine, however I fail to receive this data in my controller.

Controller:

```
public class EventOrphans
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //...
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult FindOrphanedEvents()
{
    //Some Database Logic removed
    List<EventOrphans> list = new List<EventOrphans>();
    return this.View(list);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FindOrphanedEvents(List<String> events)
{
    //This is where I stuck
}
```

View:

```
 @model List<Musa.Controllers.AdminController.EventOrphans>

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {  
 <dl class="dl-horizontal">

    @foreach (Musa.Controllers.AdminController.EventOrphans evnt in Model)
    {
        <dt>
            <input type="checkbox" name="@evnt.ID" id="@evnt.ID" checked="checked"/> 
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @evnt.Name               
        </dd>
    }
    </dl>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Abschicken" />
}
```

When I submitt the Page, the request actually hits the Controller, but the Data isnt visbile in the Controller. The content of the request looks as follows: (checked in fiddler)

```
1=on&2=on&3=on&5=on&6=on&7=on&8=on&9=on&10=on&11=on&12=on&13=on&14=on&15=on&16=on&17=on&29=on&41=on&42=on&53=on&65=on&70=on&71=on&72=on&73=on&77=on
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sib94R)**

**Model**

```
public class EventOrphans
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Checked { get; set; }

}
```

Note the Checked property

**View for loop**

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{

    <dt>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Name)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m = Model[i].Checked)
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Model[i].Name
    </dd>

}
```

Note the for loop insted of foreach to enable model binding and the hidden fields to allow the values to be posted back to the controller

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

**Controller post**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<EventOrphans> events)
{
    //All the selected events are available in events

    return View(events);
}
```

Note the change from a `List<string>` to `List<EventOrphans>`